# Create a desktop widget framework using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, desktop, widget, using

I like to create a desktop widget framework using asp.net. its like yahoo widget or google widget any one able to create a simple widget application and plug in to this framework.any one give me idea for this how to develop this framework?

Comment: You are asking how to design and build a fairly sophisticated framework, which generally requires years of experience building stuff within the platform, not a five-minute stackoverflow tip.

Answer (score 1):

For a kick off, you should take at the [W3C Widgets specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/) - that provides the framework for how widgets are packaged and distributed (and means that you get to play with existing widgets from Opera, Nokia, RIM etc rather than have to invent them all from scratch).